# Inserting a clone after the original

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to place a clone element after the original element.

I did some research and found out how to create a clone and how to place the clone after the original, but I can't seem to put them together.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onClickAdd() {

    var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("tableRow").insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>    
    <table>
        <tr id="tableRow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="textField">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="addButton" value="Add" onClick="Javascript:onClickAdd()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

My expected output would be:
Upon every click on the addButton, a new text input field will be placed at the bottom of the stack of text fields. The button is not part of the stack, and should always be below the stack.

I'm a total noob in Javascript. The code above may or may not be incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close. :-) You call it on the *parent* node (and no need to go look it up a second time):

```
function onClickAdd() {

    var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
    tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- changes here
}
```

Of course, the above creates an invalid DOM structure, because you end up with *two* rows with the same `id` value (`"tableRow"`), and `id` values **must** be unique in the document. So:

```
function onClickAdd() {

    var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
    // Clear the `id` from the clone
    tableRowClone.id = ""; // To clear it, or include something to give it its own
    tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- changes here
}
```

Comment: Just read your edit. You just answered my next question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore) on the parent element:

```
tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
```

And do not forget to change the `id`. IDs must be unique.
And, in the inline event, `Javascript:` is obsolete. It doesn't cause any errors, because it's being interpreted as a label.

Comment: What should I use instead of Javascript: ?

Comment: @paperclip Nothing. It's obsolete, which implies that your code works well when it's removed. `< ... onClick="onClickAdd();">`. Bonus note: JavaScript is case-sensitive, whereas HTML isn't. So, `onClickAdd` can only be spelled in one way, but `onClick` can also be spelled with other capitalising, such as `onclick`.

Comment: *"And, in the inline event, `Javascript:` is obsolete"* Actually, no; it was *never* required or correct. The `javascript:` pseudo-protocol is (and always was) only used in attributes where URIs are expected, such as `href` on `a` elements. (And you can still do that if you need to, although best not to put code in `href`.) It was never used in `onXyz` stuff. The text within `onXyz` is JavaScript code (and as you say, using it there creates a [label](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12)).

Answer (score 1):

```
function onClickAdd() {
    var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
    tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
}
```

And the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfK9H/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Cool stuff.