# Keeping track of duplicated elements in Javascript using JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom

This question is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117519/inserting-a-clone-after-the-original) of mine. Thanks to some help I am now able to show duplicate elements upon click on the addButton.

I would like to keep track of how many elements have been duplicated. This will also help to assign different id to the duplicate elements.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<html>

<head>
<%! int n = 1; %>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onClickAdd() {

    var tableRow = document.getElementById("tableRow");
    var tableRowClone = tableRow.cloneNode(true);
    tableRowClone.id = 'tableRow'+<%=n%>;
    tableRow.parentNode.insertBefore(tableRowClone, tableRow.nextSibling);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>    
    <table>
        <tr id="tableRow">
            <td>
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend> This is box number <%=n++%> </legend>
                    <table>
                      <tr> 
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="addButton" value="Add" onClick="Javascript:onClickAdd()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

If you read my other question, you will find the code samples similar. Now, I want to print out different legends by incrementing a JSP integer, `n`.

Thus far all duplicates show "This is box number 1" in the legend. It seems like `n` doesn't increment to 3 onwards.

I would like to show that `n` increases to assign id to the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP is generating the HTML on the *server-side* while the Javascript is running on the *client-side*. Meaning, when the Javascript is running the page was already rendered with the values of `n` (which is `1` at the time of creation). Since the JSP is not running again the value of `n` remains `1`.

Solution: run everything on the client-side (JS) including the counter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll just use Javascript to keep count. I will post my solution later using my code. Thanks!